# MainLayout.razor doesn't get AuthenticationStateProvider injected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I have a WebAssembly project, based on .net5 and based on the hybrid model between WASM and Server side, which means it's WebAssembly but .net core hosted. It's possible to choose this model during the creation of the project itself from Visual Studio. It means there is both Client and Server projects. I am trying to inject AuthenticationStateProvider in the MainLayout.razor as per documentation but unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
```

Error when starting the application:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for property 'AuthenticationStateProvider' on type 'MyApp.Blazor.Client.Shared.MainLayout'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider'.

Seems like it doesn't get injected. But in the client project I installed the  **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization** nuget and its Program.cs I added:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
```

what am I missing?